# nav pills with dropdown in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like have a `nav-pill` with a dropdown showing a few different options. To this end, this is what I have:

```
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'faq' %}">FAQ's</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

This does not seem to work however. I can see the dropdown but when I click, nothing happens. Wondering if anyone has encountered the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine for me here is the fiddle that I used https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6awest9y/ I assume you have your libraries are set up correctly load jquery js before bootstrap js.  If you do there must be some other issue with conflicting javascript or something.

Comment: @DrinkinPeople: thank you very much for your reply. It does work on jsfiddle, but for some damn reason it does not seem to work in my html :(( I do have `boostrap.js` after `jquery,js` I am very confused why this is..

Comment: OK you were right - there was conflicting JS. I had `dropdown.js` as an include and for some reason this was screwing things up. Could you please write it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine I have a working fiddle at the following link [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6awest9y/).

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'faq' %}">FAQ's</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Make sure that you have your libraries loaded in the correct order loading jquery.js first then bootstrap.js.  If this is not the problem then you more than likely have conflicting javascript.  Take out javascript files one by one and see what javascript is conflicting with bootstrap's javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As wrote `Drinkin People`, you have working code! just load your `jquery.js` script before `bootstrap.js`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/mmdvsnuz/)

Comment: please see my reply to DrinkinPeople.

Comment: @JohnJ, do you download your js-scripts below html-code but above closed `</body>` and `</html>` tags?